# Android Q background restrictions

Tags: android, android-activity, android-10.0

I need to show an activity on push received, but I am getting `Background activity start from package-name blocked.` system Toast. 
This is an authentication activity where user needs to perform some task. I do not manage phone or NFC interaction thus I don't need to actually start 'special' service but showing notification is not enough - I need that activity.
SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission doesn't help.
So, should I re-implement all my flows to work only with notifications? Is there any possibility to start activity when application was **closed** (No activity in back stack)?

Comment: "should I re-implement all my flows to work only with notifications?" -- yes. "Is there any possibility to start activity when application was closed (No activity in back stack)?" -- not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Android Q places restrictions on when apps can start activities. This behavior change helps minimize interruptions for the user and keeps the user more in control of what's shown on their screen.[You can see the full document here](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts)

**As of Android Q Beta 4, this change has the following properties:**

> 1. Affects your app if you launch activities without user interaction
> 2. Mitigate by using notification-triggered activities
> 3. Disable restrictions by turning on the Allow background activity starts developer option